# IBM MQ User Authentication for mixed case username

Tags: ibm-server, websphere

I have and IBM Wesbsphere MQ installation on a Centos server. I have set up connection authentication that allows user of a group read_group to connect and view the queues. I have created a user developer and made it a member of the read_group. From a MQ Explorer running on a Windows workstation I am add and connect to the remote queue manager running on the Centos server.

I created a user called jane.doe and made it a member of the group read_group. I am able to connect using this user from MQ Explorer.

I created a user called John.Doe and made it a member of group read_group . I am not able to connect using this user from MQ Explorer.

For good measure I created a user called Ruth and made it a member of the group read_group. I am not able to connect using this user from MQ Explorer.

The exception thrown in MQ Explorer is

```
Access not permitted.You are not authorized to perform this operation. (AMQ4036)
```

The exception in the MQ error log is

```
AMQ9557: Queue Manager UserID initialization failed for 'Ruth'

EXPLANATION:
The call to initialize the User ID 'Ruth' failed with CompCode 2 and Reason 2035

ACTION:
Correct the error and try again.
----- cmqxrsrv.c : 2321 -----------------------------------------------
```

I have confirmed the group membership for all the above users is correct. I have confirmed I can log on to Centos without any issues.

It seems like the issue is the casing of the usernames.

The queue manager has been altered in mqsc as follows

```
ALTER QMGR CONNAUTH(USE.PW)
```

AuthInfo has been defined a follows

```
DEFINE AUTHINFO(USE.PW) AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS) FAILDLAY(10) CHCKLOCL(OPTIONAL) CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED)
```

Is this a IBM MQ issue? How does one configure MQ to accept and correctly process names with uppercase letters as the OS seems to be doing?

Comment: How is `CONNAUTH` configured?   Can you provide the `AUTHINFO` object?

Comment: I have updated the detail to include information on the authinfo definition

Comment: What specific version of IBM MQ are you at? What is the rest of the `AUTHINFO`?  Are you using `OS` or `PAM` as the `AUTHENMD`